# MacBook Pro with Retina display - three external displays under Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, display, macbook-pro

Is it possible to drive three external displays (3x 22" inch monitors, each at 1680 x 1050) on my MacBook Pro with Retina display under BootCamp / Windows?

[A couple of guys have shown that it works under OS X](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJhvyLB_Tbw). Can this work under Windows as well?

Comment: The problem is that Windows does not run well wit Boot Camp. You'll have to run in 150DPI, which means your external screens will also run in 150DPI (this is a no go). You could also run in eg 1920x1200 on your retina... But that is very blurry (like going from none retina to retina, just the other way). This is also true even if you run with perfect pixel doubling 1440x900 (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59283/why-is-a-retina-macbook-running-1440x900-grainy-under-boot-camp). I've just sold my retina because it simply does not work in Windows (external screens or not). Period!

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why you could not plug three external monitors into a Mac, whether it's running OS X, or Windows under bootcamp.

There are two Thunderbolt connectors and one HDMI connector, and they all work as video outputs - the driver should be able to handle a monitor plugged into each of these.

As the comment on the question mentions, Windows does not know how to handle retina displays all that well - but for external (non-retina) monitors it should not have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just went as far as attaching two external displays (1920x1200 + 1280x1024 + the internal at native 2880x1800) and apart from the fan blowing slightly I didn't run into any problems. I don't think that three external displays at that moderate resolution of 1680x1050 pose a problem especially when you don't bump up the internal resolution to native. The guys at OWC attached two thunderbolt displays with considerably higher resolution and a FUllHD to the rMBP. If the OS X driver is able to handle it I am pretty sure the windows driver can do just as well.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it depends on which rMBP you have. Depending on the year and if you do or do not have the dedicated GPU, you may or may not be able to (easily) drive 3 external monitors.

As far as I know, none of the base model 15" rMBP (the ones without the dedicated GPU) can drive three external displays WHILE IN OS X.

Here's where this is interesting to me. 3 external monitors works PERFECTLY in Windows 10 through Bootcamp. Which means that the lack of support for 3 displays is purely software limitations and nothing to do with hardware capability. I've no idea why there would be a limitation in OS X since I feel it runs lighter than Windows 10 in the first place, but for some reason, without some sort of adapter (or an Apple TV, but who really would enjoy using a wireless Apple TV-connected display as a computer monitor?) it is impossible to run 3 external displays on a 15" rMBP unless it is equipped with the dedicated GPU.